# Making image hidden with CSS

Tags: html, css

This image overlays another image. It's added to the page with HTML generated by PHP. This is the PHP code that generates the image:

```
            Echo '<img src="images/tick.png" id="tick' . $i .'" h1 class="hidden" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>';
```

I want the image to be hidden, and I'll change it to visible when the other image is clicked. This is the CSS:

```
    h1.visible
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    h1.hidden
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you adding a `<h1>` in an `<img>` ?

Comment: What is an `<img h1>` tag...?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding your rule to an `h1` element rather than an `img`. And I have no idea what you tried to do with that `h1` attribute inside `img` - get rid of it. Try

```
echo '<img src="images/tick.png" id="tick' . $i .'" class="hidden" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>';
```

And CSS:

```
img.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That was dumb. Thanks.